# Python Console Name Customization

Tags: python, console, command-line-interface, customization

Usually the Python console looks like this:

```
>>> command
```

Is there a way to make it look like:

```
SomeText>>> command
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sys.ps1 == ">>>"
sys.ps2 == "..."
```

You can also change this in the [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file) environment variable.

For example (this is not secure), put the following in a script somewhere and set PYTHONSTARTUP to point at that script.

```
import sys
import getpass
sys.ps1  = getpass.getuser( ) + ">>> "
```

Of course, you could change the last line above to anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
import sys
import os

sys.ps1 = os.getenv("USER") + sys.ps1
```

(or `getpass.getuser()` as suggested by the other answer)

In the corrected version, it's even easier, of course:

```
import sys
sys.ps1 = "SomeText" + sys.ps1
```

Comment: I corrected the question. I don't necessary want to display the user name. Just a custom text for making some personalized screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

[IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) provides convenient way of setting sophisticated prompts as described [here](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/stable/html/config/customization.html#prompts).